# pandas - grouping values by pair of columns and pivoting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Been struggling to think what to do here, pivoting and melting and whatnot doesn't seem to be working out. I was trying to join the names of the to/from destinations together and then re-order the combined names but it was a total mess

My data concerns flows from one location to another, it's in the format:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=['from_location','to_location','flow'],data =[['a','b',1],['b','a',3]])
  from_location to_location  flow
0           a             b     1
1           b             a     3
```

but my output needs to be the format:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=['connection','flow','back flow','net'],data =[['a -> b',1,3,2]])

  connection  flow  back flow  net
0     a -> b     1          3    2
```

Any nice built in functions that can rearrange things like this? I'm not even sure what keywords to search by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#df = df.sort_values(['from_location','to_location'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['from_location','to_location']], axis=1),
                   columns=list('ab'), index=df.index)
s = df1['a'] + ' -> ' + df1['b']
df2 = df.groupby(s)['flow'].agg(['first','last']).assign(net=lambda x: x['last'] - x['first'])
print (df2)
        first  last  net
a -> b      1     3    2
```

**Explanation**:

1. If necessary first [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) if possible some paired rows are swapped
2. Sort columns per rows by [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) and join columns together with splitter
3. Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by joined values and aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html)
4. Last if need subtract columns add new column by [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

Comment: unable to understand this: `s` is a series. It is not available in the `df`. How is the groupby working then? Isn't it necessary for a column to be a part of data frame to do groupby on that column ?

Comment: @ManishSaraswat - There is no problem, because index and length of `s` and `df` is same.